# Angularjs progress bar with multiple levels?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Can anyone suggest, I have a requirement like I need to show an bar with three statuses in one bar with different colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `bootstrap` library to have stacked progress bars.

To create a stacked progress bar:

You can use the code as

```
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:40%;background-color:red">
  Free Space
</div>
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:10%">
  Warning
</div>
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:20%">
  Danger
</div>
```

to use in context of `angular` use can use `ng-repeat` on the multiple progress to add the width and color to it based on your requirement.
bar.

For your reference you can do something like

Html File

```
<html ng-App="myApp">
    <head>
        <title>My HTML File</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div class="progress" ng-controller="progressBars">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-repeat="progress in progressData"style="width:{{progress.value}}%;background-color:{{progress.color}}">
              This is {{$index +1}} bar
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Script File

```
var app = angular.module("myApp" , []);             
            app.controller("progressBars" , function($scope) {
                $scope.progressData = [{'value':20 , color:'red'},{'value':40 , color:'blue'}];

                });
```

Comment: Thank you sahil. This is fine but do we have any plugin to do like this?